# Atom editor : linter-rubocop plugin configuration error

Tags: ruby, plugins, atom-editor, rubocop

Following guidelines according to **[Atom](https://atom.io/packages/linter-rubocop).**

I have installed `gem rubocop` and the `linter-rubocop` plugin successfully and now I am trying to configure it into Atom editor, but I am facing this error

I have followed these steps on my terminal:

```
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$ gem install rubocop
Successfully installed rubocop-0.40.0
Parsing documentation for rubocop-0.40.0
Done installing documentation for rubocop after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$ apm install linter-rubocop
Installing linter-rubocop to /Users/dR/.atom/packages ✓
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$ which rubocop
/Users/dR/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rubocop
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$ rbenv which rubocop
/Users/dR/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rubocop
Dharmeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dR$
```

then after I am trying to configure **`linter-rubocop`** by editing **~/.atom/config.cson** . Next I get this error:

[image]

Please guide me to configure it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add doubles quotes around executablePath variable like: `executablePath: "/Users/dR/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rubocop"`

Comment: @YannVERY As you suggested I tried it with double quotes as well as single quotes, but it didn't work.

Comment: @DharmeshRupani is there a reason you cannot use the `linter-rubocop` package settings GUI to set the `executablePath` var?